# Windows: how to bind to <1024 port as standard user?

Tags: windows, privileges, administration, ports

I was wondering if there was a way on Windows to bind to a <1024 port as a standard user?

I am aware that this requires Admin privilege but can I approve the request with Admin but run the actual service as a lower-privileged user?

I am reconfiguring a Windows server that I did not setup and do not know who did. They have a service binding to a lower port running as Administrator but I want to run it as standard user.

Also, running is Microsoft IIS on port 80, but that is running as lower privileged 'iis/apppool' user. Is there a way to do that same thing for other services/applications?

Worst comes to worst, I will just run the service on a higher port but would be nice to keep it where it's at.

Thank you